# How to pass MQTT Topic data to Postgres on Node-Red

Tags: mqtt, iot, node-red

I am working on integrating MQTT Topic with Postgres DB on Node-Red.I have one MQTT Topic for e.g 'query/topic1' which is getting some value from a publisher, I want to save this value into Postgres database.For that, I created flow on Node-Red.I have created MQTT subscriber component which is feeding 'function' block which in turn is input to Postgres.I have written below function in 'function' component (named 'query' in the image) in Node-Red.

```
msg.payload = [
    {
        query: 'begin',
    },
    {
        query: 'select * from table1 where field2 > $param1',
    params: {
            param1: $msg.payload,
        },
        output: true,
    },
    {
        query: 'commit',
    },
];

return msg;
```

I want the "$param1" to be the value coming from MQTT topic, but I am confused how to do that.I tried using '$msg.payload' but it did not work.Can you please suggest. I am new to these stuffs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `msg.payload` in the function node.

You need to move that value to another key on the `msg` object and then update the `param1` value to point to that new key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I made one small change param1: msg.payload.It worked.